# Xamarin iOS: Unable to find simulator for iPad mini and no latest iOS version 11.4.1

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, simulator

I tried to find the iPad simulator from xCode but no iPad Mini Simulator attached.

The version 11.4.1 not available as well. I have clicked from xCode Preference -> Component but cant find the simulator. My simulator current running 11.4

Is there any 11.4.1 available?

Comment: It should has it. My iPhone has an update for that version. I’m not familiar with xcode. Maybe 11.4.1-beta?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly ,you should make sure that your Xcode is up to date. And it’s default iOS version is 11.4.
In addition,iPad mini simulator is not available in Xcode. You can choose the simulator ‘iPad Retina’ instead.It has the same Screen resolution with iPad mini 2-4（2048*1536）.

Comment: The Xcode is update to date .. can't see any more update available

Comment: The default iOS version is 11.4,can you show your Simulator list on Xcode ?